# change div style according to values passed as argument to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

here is javascript what i have tried

```js
function toggle(clicked_id,name) {
   alert(clicked_id);
   alert(name);
   var text = document.getElementById("clicked_id");
   var ele = document.getElementById("name");
   alert(ele.style.display);
   if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "+";
    text.value="+"
     }
   else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "-";
    text.value="-"
   }
   return
  }
```

and html is

```html
<input type="button" id="displayText1" onClick="return toggle(this.id,this.name)" value="+" style="margin-left:86%;" name="toggleText1">
       
       <div id="toggleText1" style="display: none"><h1>Wallet Info Here</h1></div> </div>

<input type="button" id="displayText2" onClick="toggle(this.id,this.name)" value="+" style="margin-left:86%;" name="toggleText2">
       
       <div id="toggleText2" style="display: none"><h1>Wallet Info Here</h1></div> </div>
```

i tried this but only alerts i am getting..no change in div style. That is not changing to hide or show mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove quotes around variable name

```
var text = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
var ele = document.getElementById(name);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/r0hnmkzw/)

Answer (score 1):

Issue is this:

```
var text = document.getElementById("clicked_id"); // func arg is in string format
var ele = document.getElementById("name");  // func arg is in string format
```

---

You have to use it without quotes.

```
var text = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
var ele = document.getElementById(name);
```

yet there is a better way of doing this, you can do something like this:

```
<input type="button" id="displayText1" onClick="toggle(this)" value="+" style="margin-left:86%;" name="toggleText1">

<input type="button" id="displayText2" onClick="toggle(this)" value="+" style="margin-left:86%;" name="toggleText2">
```

just pass `this` in the argument and you can change the function like this:

```
function toggle(el) {
    var text = el;
    var ele = document.getElementById(el.name);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "+";
        text.value="+"
    } else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "-";
        text.value="-"
    }
}
```

*As you don't need to return anything it is just a dom manipulation stuff, so you can remove the `return` statement.*

I suggest you to avoid inline event handlers, so if you are interested in unobtrusive javascript then you can place this event handler in a js file with that `toggle()` function and you can use it:

```
document.getElementById('displayText1').addEventListener('click', function(){
    toggle(this);
});
document.getElementById('displayText2').addEventListener('click', function(){
    toggle(this);
});
```

or with `querySelectorAll` method:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#displayText1, #displayText2').addEventListener('click', function(){
        toggle(this);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

The quotes around the variables "clicked_id" and "name" causes them to act as string. And there are no elements with these id.
Just remove the quotes and things will work out.

```
var text = document.getElementById(clicked_id);

var ele = document.getElementById(name);
```